# Property assignment not working

Tags: jquery, domready, prop

I'm trying to mimic a `placeholder` behavior, so i try to save the original value on page load. using this code. I'm here cause it's not working. the value is empty.

```
$().ready(function() {
  $("input").prop("placeHolder", $(this).val());
  /*
  also tried:
       $("input").prop("placeHolder", $(this).attr("value"));
  */
}
```

Comment: hint - what do you think `$(this)` is in the call to `.prop()` ?  It's **not** the `input` element!

Comment: Also it's "placeholder" not "placeHolder".

Comment: If it's not the `input`, what is it? **
it is `placeHolder` since i'm trying to create a new, different, property. **
 `$()` isn't it a shorthand for `$(document)`?

Comment: Yes, `$()` is shorthand for `$(document)` hence `this === document` inside the `.ready` callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").prop("placeholder", function(){
        return $(this).val()
    });
});
```

With `$().ready()` I guess you refer to the `$(document).ready()` method.

In your case `$(this)` is not referencing your `input`. It is getting the parent from wich this sentence is in. In this case the `$()`.

You can do what I wrote above or this will work too:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#input_id").prop("placeholder", $("#input_id").val());
});
```

This will work for one input, if you want another way to make it work for all inputs this will work too:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").each(function(){
        $(this).prop("placeholder", $(this).val());
    });
});
```

Notice that in this case `$(this)` does make reference to the input being iterated.

Comment: There werent answers when I wrote mine. Maybe they were written while I was writting mine and testing it.

Comment: fair enough - but your latter code only works for one element, not "all input elements"

Comment: Well, the new stuff will work, but it's worse than your original answer - `.prop` will implicitly loop over every element in the selector, so there's no need for a `.each`.  You've now got two jQuery calls per element, instead of one in your original, and none in mine.

Comment: They are just different ways to do it.

Answer (score 2):

In your original code `$(this)` is **not** the current `input` element.  It'll be whatever object is passed as `this` by `$().ready()` - probably the `document` object.  (I tested - it is!)

This should do what you require:

```
$('input').prop('placeholder', function() {
    return this.value;
});
```

This version of `.prop` will call the supplied function, passing each element in turn as `this`, allowing direct access to that DOM element's other properties.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute is case-sensitive, so it should be "placeholder. And you can use a function to set the attribute with:

```
$("input").prop("placeholder", function () {
    return $(this).val()
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/e021zg5y/)**

Comment: for an `input` element, `$(this).val() === this.value`, but the latter is _way_ more efficient

Comment: @Alnitak I *knew* you were going to say something about that.